# how to add search product form in a custom admin module

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, products, catalogsearch

I need to add the search product block in a custom admin module form.
I tried with

```
 <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_search" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="search">
                        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_search_grid" name="grid" />
                    </block>
```

The block shows but the add product functionality doesn't work. Basically I need to select products, retrieve the IDs and then save as serialised data.

Any suggestion?
thanks